# Group_by_at and summarise_ producing values when using shiny/markdown rendetable. R

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, r-markdown, rshiny

Here is my code

````
```{r}
#Assign Variables
    
    
Categorical.Variables = c( "Race/Ethnicity" ,"Gender", "Education", "Intervention")
    
Numeric.Variables = c("Age", "Pre Weight", "Post Weight", "Follow-up Weight","Wieght Loss/Gain after Intervention","Wieght Loss/Gain on Follow Up" )
```
````

And I have this simple table I'm trying to make with dplyr.

````
```{r}


renderTable({
   wl_data %>% group_by_at(input$categorical_variable) %>% 
    summarise("Average " = mean(wl_data[[input$numeric_variable]]),
      "Median " = median(wl_data[[input$numeric_variable]])
    ) 
})
```
````

This is the output I am getting which has the same value for the entire numerical input and not broken down by the categorical one.

[image]

My desired output is to have a reactive table that will give me summary statistics that change based on inputs. So far I've gotten really close but I can't figure out how to get it to work.
What am I doing wrong?

Data

```
> dput(wl_data)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 
29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 
45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 
61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 
77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 
93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100), Gender = c("Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", 
"Male"), Age = c(34.1958081813646, 38.342817530618, 31.4255555318668, 
39.9174711825326, 30.4606180330738, 35.0906190911774, 33.4250614438206, 
32.4111385603901, 30.9181484377477, 25.1908965916373, 33.1378793967888, 
37.1778275772231, 33.7549078873126, 30.3750618664781, 40.9762685345486, 
27.3728471407667, 36.3470769267296, 33.8341794455191, 36.9817041397328, 
32.4507015799172, 31.736502675456, 29.6957238939358, 36.1113904697122, 
33.9414452506462, 36.9691713027423, 34.3095768736093, 32.6794349499396, 
32.5801726981881, 27.2223803373054, 34.2432519724825, 36.7139034247957, 
27.5831041259225, 41.5007923189551, 37.1082421375904, 30.3266722008702, 
33.9694667824078, 35.6325324142817, 35.2054973669583, 29.9515829434386, 
25.677076079417, 31.1902828949387, 32.4210338627454, 28.3575206745882, 
32.5940152075491, 31.9765592545155, 41.3789200289175, 36.1047693482833, 
41.7112493929453, 31.2430063028005, 34.3678300092579, 33.7714243110968, 
27.4467708701268, 31.7782484822674, 27.5600393402856, 33.2923297870439, 
38.9376543504186, 36.1805939215701, 36.2597199606244, 30.7401512296638, 
27.6097705105785, 37.7263165470213, 30.2310251905583, 32.0336846167338, 
30.4912316247355, 37.9383197620045, 29.5154438541504, 36.9983115129871, 
32.7947406882304, 33.9285486157751, 31.0574057190097, 26.5039522824809, 
31.8339186529629, 32.5527787177707, 31.8562467478914, 34.1271822586423, 
26.0893318378367, 32.6484211806091, 32.8446673998842, 35.6959423848893, 
38.4928932513576, 30.124668880133, 29.9166947266785, 35.4745850168983, 
31.8399849826237, 34.1574638847378, 33.9537143341731, 32.5872485669679, 
33.5270658220979, 31.9265234034974, 32.4627478372422, 29.9351938489126, 
34.0414714779472, 31.2413191901287, 27.0438647172414, 19.2909317016602, 
33.415520844399, 27.2705926514463, 42.3596463557333, 29.8770043778932, 
33.5144147507963), Education = c("Less than HS", "Less than HS", 
"Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", 
"Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", 
"Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", 
"Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", 
"Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", "Less than HS", 
"Less than HS", "Less than HS", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", 
"HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", 
"HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", 
"HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "HS Diploma", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "Some College", "Some College", "Some College", 
"Some College", "College Degree"), Ethnicity = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), `Pre Weight` = c(192.056576386152, 
199.200034264708, 206.876365089032, 195.881563220086, 200.023472577799, 
209.835274224519, 197.638006672991, 188.53439444449, 197.556054379151, 
195.261374235473, 183.834639690234, 206.592420843139, 201.388593429714, 
210.134243322886, 210.711872502929, 191.050579749048, 197.758412402822, 
194.271341504122, 198.923689983916, 198.967602661854, 192.920791894197, 
203.365595032141, 199.845179783937, 196.529509982996, 209.761359590106, 
195.030192050966, 191.221678439819, 188.893717611267, 205.644104360021, 
193.924385191553, 195.469716734282, 205.8901999839, 201.684244009288, 
199.956401891017, 202.022335022251, 204.845240593771, 201.497865807527, 
214.361511032097, 190.574097748526, 197.017952975715, 200.709252046567, 
196.371000972635, 185.010079737753, 197.991679603932, 201.731562744884, 
206.684686806897, 198.528149601247, 190.756862982584, 201.257889946122, 
201.911622232205, 202.823506631306, 192.12975887733, 196.74718730805, 
197.705610551042, 198.324502368836, 199.593768163526, 183.679870976834, 
195.266928974364, 195.89751916776, 209.72831764759, 198.465869677806, 
207.538604561181, 205.284033133852, 195.080391611031, 193.136535406142, 
202.807351731666, 194.04551510654, 201.363628937019, 200.066255208571, 
203.038557790409, 191.260291037383, 200.227987240782, 201.838208956746, 
196.743805124628, 195.478231878427, 202.583284069464, 191.771438428463, 
206.52146661398, 193.483762293385, 190.160595982365, 206.933106189739, 
206.326923423534, 205.130903784651, 198.517406195082, 202.249084556955, 
200.390387751599, 199.138963969221, 204.348338163458, 198.339567011702, 
197.763306621186, 198.144029061426, 191.630341694166, 202.501124865579, 
210.04412604036, 202.621188398029, 207.952265488915, 197.56589056435, 
197.411320802916, 199.215568434214, 195.430133251124), Intervention = c("Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", "Placebo Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", 
"Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Diet", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", 
"Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout", "Adjusted Workout"), 
    `Post Weight` = c(183.884925652295, 199.800326915851, 194.671078067971, 
    203.366324901639, 200.073624389392, 198.747637957626, 197.077328200452, 
    205.294385457295, 203.63121523353, 202.319217967146, 194.309724454273, 
    204.37792175237, 201.774254426186, 199.169666236616, 196.435276100077, 
    188.147545420565, 192.339179127361, 197.267082901293, 193.759855326265, 
    194.147504705528, 210.371321306797, 198.317242327379, 193.102086020575, 
    186.002956913784, 187.153649610467, 197.444735638259, 199.397255917051, 
    199.896955043572, 200.289578221986, 200.359694579151, 194.154234966321, 
    201.103945462295, 198.381657289632, 174.026079230011, 195.176185252116, 
    192.193440534233, 189.540944711247, 195.402285634977, 190.26270833789, 
    188.311830833904, 193.327807801019, 186.754787273152, 189.741880512578, 
    184.221094195585, 194.408037395682, 187.552772240146, 178.570551406359, 
    199.402663974673, 189.554024381927, 195.699110599584, 196.260223355843, 
    184.848634171125, 194.972185590508, 186.89522462379, 195.963659870962, 
    189.975194325292, 185.117492173653, 188.429422814501, 191.845467861334, 
    184.460234458733, 181.766015566303, 195.604591362702, 185.29349076713, 
    185.749602360069, 186.493563341777, 194.774700184702, 170.250064507127, 
    192.264929460362, 194.279346537951, 194.095480815304, 192.09355792118, 
    205.814604264742, 201.010346295516, 205.747699560743, 209.566269909556, 
    196.717178873951, 190.261858329177, 210.87666987587, 184.596615831833, 
    200.588227067055, 204.084495230927, 185.477325026295, 206.07568608757, 
    199.725719135313, 193.537903719698, 202.579156443971, 204.824664756597, 
    197.221812009229, 181.948258209741, 198.307839632616, 212.828922990593, 
    183.819634508109, 209.631753528083, 201.93635969481, 191.993820458447, 
    210.423491403344, 196.130759427615, 216.762351151556, 194.786605839181, 
    214.179886420607), `Follow-up Weight` = c(196.754451103698, 
    216.156309357029, 210.484507129149, 180.150482770114, 192.390769421036, 
    203.047307473025, 212.955081274413, 181.630344336736, 194.986069395964, 
    189.119214660604, 210.027861208073, 191.293032053363, 210.267319794366, 
    209.707298431749, 187.987575877924, 174.893785292807, 205.768015398644, 
    198.770255160707, 211.5933289635, 182.237056883605, 175.814034769428, 
    202.397501930318, 180.344375671848, 211.968205626545, 222.363337848219, 
    179.163385432912, 205.026072358305, 188.93023303026, 198.485623109445, 
    219.364188119653, 175.826722220518, 176.65140654135, 198.980842974561, 
    232.273055694532, 202.227960749224, 221.662799554178, 212.652799341595, 
    164.536254992709, 181.760834089073, 197.487373093463, 204.981188794773, 
    219.285266716906, 230.166802389431, 185.610656949575, 202.313856839464, 
    191.789445630275, 198.555966840286, 181.177552399458, 200.24041355573, 
    198.072104290259, 190.301193975029, 186.122213613271, 180.075892835885, 
    207.392077350232, 193.10916223294, 192.415564520343, 208.723270639166, 
    214.108275081526, 206.051982381905, 205.617556553261, 223.241295821208, 
    206.747063707735, 222.621179596172, 193.962939015546, 191.982042502059, 
    183.000486736273, 194.58624415638, 203.504464984871, 192.261302850238, 
    217.979959920922, 206.377081263054, 190.020876339258, 207.567484772153, 
    191.626350492879, 206.334397539831, 214.376621493284, 204.515487717072, 
    195.394387042325, 190.006551797705, 179.74960024294, 223.11257958354, 
    205.544995929085, 191.169158874982, 177.952415974869, 190.496962709585, 
    200.471106886835, 185.645138167456, 214.420277238969, 219.606989098975, 
    183.150109983399, 209.9404815046, 205.259732915874, 195.812441966336, 
    197.740712842642, 181.31540905888, 221.787286641484, 207.900393939053, 
    180.352527018113, 245.932392822579, 213.72185352011), `Race/Ethnicity` = c("Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", 
    "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "Hispanic", "White", 
    "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", "White", 
    "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", 
    "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black", "Black"), `Wieght Loss/Gain after Intervention` = c(8.17165073385695, 
    -0.600292651142809, 12.2052870210609, -7.48476168155321, 
    -0.0501518115925137, 11.0876362668932, 0.560678472538712, 
    -16.7599910128047, -6.07516085437965, -7.05784373167262, 
    -10.4750847640389, 2.2144990907691, -0.385660996471415, 10.9645770862699, 
    14.2765964028513, 2.90303432848305, 5.41923327546101, -2.99574139717151, 
    5.16383465765102, 4.82009795632621, -17.4505294125993, 5.04835270476178, 
    6.74309376336168, 10.5265530692122, 22.6077099796385, -2.41454358729243, 
    -8.17557747723185, -11.0032374323055, 5.354526138035, -6.43530938759795, 
    1.31548176796059, 4.78625452160486, 3.30258671965566, 25.9303226610064, 
    6.84614977013553, 12.6518000595388, 11.95692109628, 18.9592253971205, 
    0.311389410635456, 8.70612214181165, 7.38144424554775, 9.61621369948261, 
    -4.73180077482539, 13.770585408347, 7.3235253492021, 19.1319145667512, 
    19.9575981948874, -8.64580099208979, 11.7038655641954, 6.21251163262059, 
    6.56328327546362, 7.28112470620545, 1.77500171754218, 10.8103859272524, 
    2.36084249787382, 9.61857383823371, -1.43762119681924, 6.83750615986355, 
    4.05205130642571, 25.2680831888574, 16.6998541115026, 11.9340131984791, 
    19.9905423667224, 9.33078925096197, 6.64297206436459, 8.03265154696419, 
    23.795450599413, 9.0986994766572, 5.7869086706196, 8.94307697510521, 
    -0.833266883797478, -5.58661702396057, 0.827862661230029, 
    -9.00389443611493, -14.0880380311282, 5.86610519551323, 1.50958009928581, 
    -4.35520326188998, 8.88714646155131, -10.4276310846908, 2.84861095881206, 
    20.8495983972389, -0.944782302918611, -1.20831294023083, 
    8.71118083725742, -2.18876869237283, -5.68570078737685, 7.12652615422849, 
    16.3913088019617, -0.544533011430758, -14.6848939291667, 
    7.8107071860577, -7.13062866250402, 8.10776634555077, 10.6273679395817, 
    -2.47122591442894, 1.43513113673544, -19.3510303486401, 4.42896259503323, 
    -18.7497531694826), `Wieght Loss/Gain on Follow Up` = c(-12.8695254514023, 
    -16.3559824411786, -15.8134290611779, 23.2158421315253, 7.68285496835597, 
    -4.29966951539973, -15.8777530739608, 23.664041120559, 8.64514583756682, 
    13.2000033065415, -15.7181367537996, 13.0848896990065, -8.4930653681804, 
    -10.5376321951335, 8.4477002221538, 13.2537601277581, -13.4288362712832, 
    -1.50317225941399, -17.8334736372344, 11.9104478219233, 34.5572865373688, 
    -4.0802596029389, 12.7577103487274, -25.9652487127605, -35.2096882377518, 
    18.2813502053468, -5.62881644125446, 10.9667220133124, 1.80395511254028, 
    -19.0044935405022, 18.3275127458037, 24.4525389209448, -0.599185684928671, 
    -58.2469764645211, -7.05177549710788, -29.4693590199458, 
    -23.1118546303478, 30.866030642268, 8.50187424881733, -9.17554225955973, 
    -11.6533809937537, -32.5304794437543, -40.4249218768527, 
    -1.38956275398959, -7.90581944378209, -4.236673390129, -19.9854154339264, 
    18.2251115752151, -10.686389173803, -2.37299369067478, 5.95902938081417, 
    -1.273579442146, 14.8962927546236, -20.4968527264427, 2.85449763802171, 
    -2.44037019505049, -23.6057784655131, -25.6788522670249, 
    -14.2065145205706, -21.1573220945284, -41.4752802549046, 
    -11.1424723450327, -37.327688829042, -8.21333665547718, -5.48847916028171, 
    11.7742134484288, -24.3361796492536, -11.2395355245098, 2.01804368771263, 
    -23.8844791056181, -14.2835233418737, 15.7937279254838, -6.55713847663719, 
    14.1213490678638, 3.23187236972444, -17.6594426193333, -14.2536293878948, 
    15.4822828335455, -5.40993596587214, 20.8386268241156, -19.0280843526125, 
    -20.0676709027903, 14.9065272125881, 21.7733031604439, 3.04094101011287, 
    2.10804955713684, 19.1795265891415, -17.1984652297397, -37.658730889234, 
    15.1577296492178, 2.8884414859931, -21.4400984077656, 13.8193115617469, 
    4.19564685216756, 10.6784113995673, -11.3637952381396, -11.7696345114382, 
    36.4098241334432, -51.1457869833976, 0.458032900496619)), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Additional Code Chunk
Error Photo: [image]
```{r}

````
renderTable({
   wl_data %>% group_by(across(all_of(input$categorical_variable))) %>% 
    summarise("Average " = mean(.data[[input$numeric_variable]]),
      "Median " = median(.data[[input$numeric_variable]]),
      "Freq " = count(.data[[input$categorical_variable]])
    ) 
})
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mean(wl_data[[input$numeric_variable]])` is extracting the mean from the entire dataframe and does not respect the grouping. Try using `.data` instead.

Also `group_by_at` has been superseded and we may use `across`.

```
renderTable({
  wl_data %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(input$categorical_variable))) %>% 
    summarise(Average = mean(.data[[input$numeric_variable]]),
              Median = median(.data[[input$numeric_variable]])
    )
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer - this worked perfectly - do you know why I would get an error using tally() or count() with the method provided above?

Comment: How are you using it? `wl_data %>% count(.data[[input$categorical_variable]])` should work.

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to work with the summarise. I added a new chunk of code and screenshot of my error.

Comment: `count` is not the the right function there. For frequency you can just use `n()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using your data, here's a simple Shiny app that does what I think you want:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

categorical_variables = c( "Race/Ethnicity" ,"Gender", "Education", "Intervention")
numeric_variables = c("Age", "Pre Weight", "Post Weight", "Follow-up Weight","Wieght Loss/Gain after Intervention","Wieght Loss/Gain on Follow Up" )

ui <- {
    fluidPage(
        selectInput("categorical_var",
            "Select categorical variable",
            choices = categorical_variables
        ),
        selectInput("numeric_var",
            "Select numeric variable",
            choices = numeric_variables
        ),
        DTOutput("tbl")
    )
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
        dat %>%
            group_by(!!sym(input$categorical_var)) %>%
            summarise(
                mean = mean(!!sym(input$numeric_var)),
                median = median(!!sym(input$numeric_var))
            )
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

A couple of points:

- `group_by_at` is deprecated, don't use that any more
- You're making your `group_by`/`summarise` more complicated than it needs to be -- it can do the work for you :)